# Python multiprocess profiling

Tags: python, multiprocessing, cprofile

I want to profile a simple multi-process Python script. I tried this code:

```
import multiprocessing
import cProfile
import time
def worker(num):
    time.sleep(3)
    print 'Worker:', num

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(5):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(i,))
        cProfile.run('p.start()', 'prof%d.prof' %i)
```

I'm starting 5 processes and therefore cProfile generates 5 different files. Each log only shows what happens inside the `start` method. How can I get logs that profile the `worker` function (and show that it took approximately 3 seconds in each case)?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You're profiling the process startup, which is why you're only seeing what happens in `p.start()` as you say—and `p.start()` returns once the subprocess is kicked off.  You need to profile inside the `worker` method, which will get called in the subprocesses.

Comment: Wow! I feel dumb :) this was so simple. Thank you very much! And thank you for the quick response.

Comment: You bet.  And thank you for taking good care of your question!

Comment: could you illustrate how to do that?

Comment: @DavoudTaghawi-Nejad See the "Working example" in the question.

Answer (score 11):

It's not cool enough having to change your source code for profiling. Let's see what your code is supposed to be like:

```
import multiprocessing
import time
def worker(num):
    time.sleep(3)
    print('Worker:', num)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    processes = []
    for i in range(5):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(i,))
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)
    for p in processes:
        p.join()
```

I added `join` here so your main process will wait for your workers before quitting.

Instead of cProfile, try `viztracer`.

Install it by `pip install viztracer`. Then use the multiprocess feature

`viztracer --log_multiprocess your_script.py`

It will generate an html file showing every process on a timeline. (use AWSD to zoom/navigate)

[image: result of script]

Of course this includes some info that you are not interested in(like the structure of the actual multiprocessing library). If you are already satisfied with this, you are good to go. However, if you want a clearer graph for only your function `worker()`. Try `log_sparse` feature.

First, decorate the function you want to log with `@log_sparse`

```
from viztracer import log_sparse

@log_sparse
def worker(num):
    time.sleep(3)
    print('Worker:', num)
```

Then run `viztracer --log_multiprocess --log_sparse your_script.py`

[image: sparse log]

Only your worker function, taking 3s, will be displayed on the timeline.

Comment: make sure you tune `--tracer_entries`, so that you can open your file in the browser (otherwise tab always crashes for me) and at the same time `--max_stack_depth` so that all relevant data are there and are not overwritten by other (I saw only one call of my function when in fact there were many).

Answer (score 3):

If you have a complex processes structure and you want to profile a particular portion of the code, or maybe the particular working core of the process you can point to the profiler to collect stats there (see enable and disable methods https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/profile.html#module-cProfile). This is what you can do:

```
import cProfile

def my_particular_worker_code()
    pr = cProfile.Profile()
    pr.enable()

    # Process stuff to be profiled

    pr.disable()
    pr.print_stats(sort='tottime')  # sort as you wish
```

You can drop the reports to a file as well.