# Naive multiprocessing in Python with NumPy

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Despite the warnings and confused feelings I got from the ton of questions that have been asked on the subject, especially on StackOverflow, I paralellized a naive version of an embarassingly parallel problem (basically **read-image-do-stuff-return** for a list of many images), returned the resulting NumPy array for each computation and updated a global NumPy array via the `callback` parameter, and immediately got a **x5 speedup** on a 8-core machine.

Now, I probably didn't get x8 because of the lock required by each callback call, but what I got is encouraging.

I'm trying to find out if this can be improved upon, or if this is a good result. Questions :

- I suppose the returned NumPy arrays got pickled?
- Were the underlying NumPy buffers *copied* or just *passed by reference*?
- How can I find out what the bottleneck is? Any particularly useful technique?
- Can I improve on that or is such an improvement pretty common in such cases?

Comment: It's going to be pretty hard to give any sort of robust answer to most of these questions...

Comment: @mgilson: Well, it does work pretty well as it is. I just wanted to know a bit more about what it does under the hood. I'm especially unsure about exactly _which_ objects get pickled, copied or anything else. The Python profiler does not say anything about the subprocesses, unfortunately, so I wasn't able to clearly determine the overhead of using `multiprocessing` that way! Any idea is welcome ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Note: This answer is how I ended up solving the issue, but Velimir's answer is more suited if you're doing intense transfers between your processes. I don't, so I didn't need `sharedmem`.*

## How I did it

It turns out that the time spent pickling my NumPy arrays was negligible, and I was worrying too much. Essentially, what I'm doing is a MapReduce operation, so I'm doing this :

- First, on Unix systems, any object you instantiate before spawning a process will be present (and copied) in the context of the process if needed. This is called **copy-on-write** (COW), and is handled automagically by the kernel, so it's pretty fast (and definitely fast enough for my purposes). The docs contained a lot of warnings about objects needing pickling, but here I didn't need that at all for my inputs.
- Then, I ended up **loading my images from the disk**, from *within* each process. Each image is individually processed (mapped) by its own worker, so I neither lock nor send large batches of data, and I don't have any performance loss.
- Each worker does its own reduction for the mapped images it handles, then **sends the result to the main process with a `Queue`**. The usual outputs I get from the reduction function are 32-bit float images with 4 or 5 channels, with sizes close to 5000 x 5000 pixels (~300 or 400MB of memory each).
- Finally, I retrieve the intermediate reduction outputs from each process, then do a final reduction in the main process.

I'm not seeing any performance loss when transferring my images with a queue, even when they're eating up a few hundred megabytes. I ran that on a 6 core workstation (with HyperThreading, so the OS sees 12 logical cores), and using `multiprocessing` with 6 cores was 6 times faster than without using `multiprocessing`.

*(Strangely, running it on the full 12 cores wasn't any faster than 6, but I suspect it has to do with the limitations of HyperThreading.)*

## Profiling

Another of my concerns was profiling and quantifying how much overhead `multiprocessing` was generating. Here are a few useful techniques I learned :

- Compared to the built-in (at least in my shell) `time` command, the `time` *executable* (`/usr/bin/time` in Ubuntu) gives out much more information, including things such as average RSS, context switches, average %CPU,... I run it like this to get everything I can :

  ```
   $ /usr/bin/time -v python test.py
  ```
- Profiling (with `%run -p` or `%prun` in IPython) only profiles the main process. You can hook `cProfile` to every process you spawn and save the individual profiles to the disk, like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041683/python-multiprocess-profiling).

  I suggest adding a `DEBUG_PROFILE` flag of some kind that toggles this on/off, you never know when you might need it.
- Last but not least, you can get some more or less useful information from a syscall profile (mostly to see if the OS isn't taking ages transferring heaps of data between the processes), by attaching to one of your running Python processes like :

  ```
   $ sudo strace -c -p <python-process-id>
  ```

Comment: So it sounds like your program is disk bound. And since you still got 6x speedup, the CPU's cores must have parallel access to disk. And since you **only** got 6x speedup instead of 12x must mean that the hardware thread pairs (on each core) share a single disk access resource.

Comment: And, apparently on an X5550 processor, even if your program was memory bound, you'd still only get 6x, according to this: http://superuser.com/a/279803

Comment: I'm using a pretty fast SSD and the disk reads are not maxed up, but I suspected something like what you said. 6 cores are more than enough for me, so I don't mind, but it's interesting to note that the 12 cores people boast about can only do the work of half that under some conditions ;)

Answer (score 0):

I've had great success sharing large NumPy arrays (by reference, of course) between multiple processes using `sharedmem` module: https://bitbucket.org/cleemesser/numpy-sharedmem. Basically it suppresses pickling that normally happens when passing around NumPy arrays. All you have to do is, instead of:

```
import numpy as np
foo = np.empty(1000000)
```

do this:

```
import sharedmem
foo = sharedmem.empty(1000000)
```

and off you go passing `foo` from one process to another, like:

```
q = multiprocessing.Queue()
...
q.put(foo)
```

Note however, that this module has a known possibility of a memory leak upon ungraceful program exit, described to some extent here: http://grokbase.com/t/python/python-list/1144s75ps4/multiprocessing-shared-memory-vs-pickled-copies.

Hope this helps. I use the module to speed up live image processing on multi-core machines (my project is https://github.com/vmlaker/sherlock.)

Comment: Ah, I must confess I forgot about this question, sorry about that! Since it was a bit too big for a comment, I added an answer about how I ended up doing this, it might be interesting to you or others. Not sure which one I have to accept though...?