# Profiling Python code that uses multiprocessing?

Tags: python, profiling, cprofile

I have a simple producer consumer pattern set up in part of my gui code. I'm attempting to profile just the specific consumer section to see if there's any chance for optimization. However, when attempting to run the code with `python -m cProfile -o out.txt myscript.py` I'm getting an error thrown from Python's `pickle` module.

```
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 374, in main
    self = load(from_parent)
  File "c:\python27\lib\pickle.py", line 1378, in load
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "c:\python27\lib\pickle.py", line 858, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "c:\python27\lib\pickle.py", line 880, in load_eof
    raise EOFError
EOFError
```

The basic pattern in the code is

```
class MyProcess(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, in_queue, msg_queue):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.in_queue = in_queue
        self.ext_msg_queue = msg_queue
        self.name == multiprocessing.current_process().name

    def run(self):
        ## Do Stuff with the queued items
```

This is usually fed tasks from the GUI side of things, but for testing purposes, I set it up as follows.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    meg_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    p = Grabber(queue)
    p.daemon = True
    p.start()
    time.sleep(20)
    p.join()
```

But upon trying start the script, I get the above error message.

Is there a way around the error?

Answer (score 9):

In my understanding the `cProfile` module doesn't play well with `multiprocessing` on the command line. (See [Python multiprocess profiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041683/python-multiprocess-profiling).)

One way to work around this is to run the profiler from within your code -- in particular, you'll need to set up a different profiler output file for each process in your pool. You can do this pretty easily by making a call to `cProfile.runctx('a+b', globals(), locals(), 'profile-%s.out' % process_name)`.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html#module-cProfile