# Python multithreaded profiling for method that uses background process workers

Tags: python, redis, profiling, python-multithreading, cprofile

I'm trying to find the best way to profile a method that uses [redis queue](http://python-rq.org/) to set a number of jobs for running workers, waits till they're done, and returns.

I tried using [cProfile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html#module-cProfile), but it just profiles what's going on in the main thread. Is there a way to configure it to see what's going on with the workers, or another tool that can do this?

Comment: You can use [yappi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/yappi) or you can profile each thread. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041683/python-multiprocess-profiling?rq=1) you can find a sample.

Comment: Thank you. The yappi page seems to be leading to a lot of dead links however, and no api docs seem to be available?

Comment: I found (another one)[http://www.pyvmmonitor.com/license.html]. It could be nice.