# How do I use cProfile and multiprocessing pool?

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, profile, cprofile

Is there a way to use cProfile (or any profiler) with multiprocessing pools?

I'm used to using cProfile like `python -m cProfile myscript.py` but now that I mainly use multiprocessing that doesn't work. I've been reading the docs and various sites to try get it to work with multiprocessing but I'm a bit stuck - any help appreciated.

This works other than for processes in the threads:

```
import cProfile, pstats, io
from pstats import SortKey
from multiprocessing import Pool

def threaded_func(x):
    for i in range(11111111):
        if i%10000000 == 0:
            print (x)
        
pr = cProfile.Profile()
pr.enable()

a = [1,2]
with Pool(processes=2) as pool:
    pool.map(threaded_func, a)
    
threaded_func(3)

pr.disable()
s = io.StringIO()
sortby = SortKey.CUMULATIVE
ps = pstats.Stats(pr, stream=s).sort_stats(sortby)
ps.print_stats()
print (s.getvalue())
```

i.e., I can see the threaded_func(3) call and all the details of the pooling, but not the calls to threaded_func in the threads:

```
   Ordered by: cumulative time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        4    0.000    0.000    1.371    0.343 /Library/Python/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:3230(run_code)
        4    0.000    0.000    1.371    0.343 {built-in method builtins.exec}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.735    0.735 <ipython-input-123-ea84061719c4>:14(<module>)
        8    0.000    0.000    0.653    0.082 /Library/Python/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py:534(wait)
        8    0.000    0.000    0.653    0.082 /Library/Python/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py:264(wait)
       53    0.653    0.012    0.653    0.012 {method 'acquire' of '_thread.lock' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.651    0.651 /Library/Python/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py:285(map)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.651    0.651 /Library/Python/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py:676(get)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.651    0.651 /Library/Python/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py:673(wait)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.635    0.635 <ipython-input-123-ea84061719c4>:17(<module>)
        1    0.635    0.635    0.635    0.635 <ipython-input-123-ea84061719c4>:5(threaded_func)
```

How do I see whats in the threads?

Comment: have you seen [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041683/python-multiprocess-profiling)?

Comment: Thanks @Azat that still relevant?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python multiprocess profiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041683/python-multiprocess-profiling)