# Monitoring CPU- and Memory-Usage per process

Tags: python, multithreading, memory, multiprocessing, cpu-usage

When using multiprocessing and running multiple processes simultaneously in python, is there a way to monitor the CPU- and Memory-Usage per process?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python multiprocess profiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041683/python-multiprocess-profiling)

Comment: Thank you very much! cProfile seems like what i was looking for!