# Diagnosing Python Multiprocessing Bottleneck

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am coding a [phase retrieval algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_retrieval) and am currently stuck with what I think is a bad multiprocessing speedup, given the problem.

The algorithm itself is composed of an iterative sequence of float operations on a numpy matrix whose size is on the order of 10-100 MB.

No IO operations are done while the algorithm is running.
Parallelization just amounts to running several of these iterative procedures in parallel using [multiprocessing.Process](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process).

I tested the program on a node with 40 physical CPU Cores (80 threads) and 250 GB RAM.

Given that there is no communication between the processes and no IO calls I expected a multiprocessing speedup somewhere between 40 and 80 times on this node (was this naive ?).
However the best I could achieve was a speedup of about 20 using 40 parallel Processes.

To diagnose I used cProfile on a random process which is part of a run with 1,40 and 70 parallel executions.

It tuns out that the relative amount of time spent for each sub part of the iterative procedure stays roughly constant for all three tests but each individual operation takes much longer. This is to the point where a simple call to [numpy.conjugate](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.conjugate.html) takes 4 to 5 times longer in the 70 parallel processes case as compared to the single process case. Here are some Snakeviz diagrams:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Clearly I am running into some kind of bottleneck but what is it and how to further diagnose?

RAM space is not a problem the 250GB are more than enough.
Could RAM bandwidth be an issue ? How to check that?
The CPU-core usage of a single process in all cases is close to 100%. With 80 available "cores" this results in roughly 1%,50%,90% overall CPU usage for the 1,40 and 70 parallel processes case.

**EDIT**

Here is a minimum working example just using numpy.conjugate()

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import time
import numpy as np
import timeit
import os
os.environ['OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS'] = '1'
os.environ['MKL_NUM_THREADS'] = '1'

def f(q):
    a = np.random.rand(64,254,128) + 1.j*np.random.rand(64,254,128)
    start = time.time()
    for i in range(10):
        a.conj()
    duration = time.time()-start
    q.put(duration)

def speed_test(number_of_processes=1):
    number_of_processes = number_of_processes
    process_list=[]
    queue = Queue()
    #Start processes
    for p_id in range(number_of_processes):
        p = Process(target=f,args=(queue,))
        process_list.append(p)
        p.start()
    #Wait until all processes are finished
    for p in process_list:
        p.join()

    output = []
    while queue.qsize() != 0:
        output.append(queue.get())
    return np.mean(output)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = speed_test(number_of_processes=1)
    p40 = speed_test(number_of_processes=40)
    p70 = speed_test(number_of_processes=70)
    print('\n  1 process took {} seconds\n 40 processses took {} seconds \n 70 processes took {} seconds'.format(p1,p40,p70))
```

The numpy.conjugate() part of this code runs about 5 times slower if executed in parallel on 70 cores compared to executing it on a single core. I would have expected a much lower runtime difference what is causing this?

**EDIT 2**
On suggestion from @Ahmed AEK, here is a plot of the timings for different array sizes.
[image]

And for bigger matrices:
[image]

Thanks for reading the post!
If I can provide further data just let me know.

Comment: It'd be much easier to help here if you showed the actual problematic code!

Comment: If the CPU utilization is running *very* close to 100%, then you need to tone down the number of subprocesses you create. Seems like that is also what's causing the calls to slow down. Also is each process creating it's own matrix or are you passing it as an argument when spawning the process?

Comment: The problem is that the code is to extensive to post here. The speed reduction happens uniformly over many different sup parts of the program. There is not one single step that is responsible for the speed reduction. Thats why I posted the numpy conj example. Which are really just calls to numpy.conjugate() using matrices of the  same size.

Comment: To clarify the overall CPU utilization is not close to 100 percent, only the individual core on which a process runs. In the examples above I spawn 1, 40 or 70 processes in parallel, the total CPU utilization is in accordance with that roughly 1%,50% and 90%.

Comment: Each process creates its own matrix.

Comment: This is why creating a [mcve] is important. At the moment we can just speculate on what is happening. Write down a small program with minimal parameterization of your setup, slightly add complexity until you are able to reproduce the problem then you will have a MCVE and most probably it will pin down the root cause of your issue. Also states what is the expected output and why you think there is an issue.

Comment: You are right. I'll do so and post an update.

Comment: IIRC hyperthreading is only useful for codes with a lot of sequential operations (if conditions and long dependency chains, wait on external resources, etc). therefore for a highly vectorized/pipelined code such as conjugate there is no benefit from hyperthreading, the ALU is already doing 1 operation per cycle, and hyperthreading just causes threads to compete over the use of the ALU.

Comment: As for the reason why running 40 threads makes a single thread run slower, there are many reasons such as thermal throttling and memory bandwidth per core and cache size that make multiple threads slower than a single thread, this is completely normal, the large number of cores on servers are to handle multiple users IO bound operations, not to boost numerical performance, if you want numerical performance you should go for a GPU (APU), not a CPU.

Comment: That could indeed be the cause of the slowdown. Since even in the case where I only run 40 processes (same number as physical CPU cores) some of them might be scheduled to run on the same cpu core. I'll try to run the code without hyper-threading.

Comment: @Tim Try and see if including a `sleep(0.1)` in the `for` loop (inside `f`) brings down the *relative* time to compete each iteration of `speed_test`. It will be overall slower, but if the values are less spread-out, then you know it's the cpu that's throttling since adding a `sleep` gives it time to service other requests.

Comment: @Charchit Tried it. That indeed brings down the relative timings to the order of a few percent. So it's the CPU throttling. Thermals are not a cause for this, the core temps are below 70 °C at all times also for long workloads.

Comment: consider plotting a line between the size of the matrix first dimension (1 to 64) and the time it takes to do the operation, if it is a straight line then cache is not a problem either, if the slope changes at some point then it's probably cache size limitation, be sure to take a lot of averages, as it would otherwise look very noisy.